# Fibration with CW-complex as basespace admits retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Suppose $f:E\rightarrow B$ has the right lifting property with respect to all CW-pairs $(X,A)$. Then $f$ is a Serre fibration and also a weak-homotopy equivalence. But want i want to prove is the following: Suppose $B$ is a CW-complex. Then $f$ admits a section.

My idea was to take the CW-pair $(B,\varnothing)$, but the question is, is this the good choice or has one to use other deep theorems about that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works perfectly. No?

Comment: @ZhenLin : I don't know what to do with the map $\varnothing\rightarrow E$. I know that this is the empty map. Makes this trivial that the square commutes (which belongs to the serre fibration)?

Comment: Yes, the square commutes, so there is a lift. It's really that simple!

Comment: Okay, thank you very much :)